# Android Studio Debugging does not demand for permission?

Tags: android, android-studio

A small question: I am trying to debug my App, developing in Android Studio, with my Smartphone. I have listed several uses-permission in my manifest. But when I debug the app, the smartphone does not ask me for the permission to use the permissions... will I nevertheless have access to my "uses-permission" permissions? If not, how can I debug it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime permissions are a new thing on Android. They only work if your both Target API and the device you are using are level 23 or higher. If any of those is lower, then Runtime permissions do not work and old permission model is used. In old model, permissions are granted at install time and when you install your app via USB, you automatically accept all permissions. Still, in new permission model, you need to write code in async style, meaning that first you have to ask user for permission and supply a callback, in which you will know whether the user granted or denied specific permission. You can read more about that at [officials docs.](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)